# Why is -replace not working as described in this powershell script?

Tags: powershell

The input text from allacts.txt is:

```
institutionId: blah blah,name: 1st thing,laestabNo: blah blah   institutionId: blah blah,name: 2nd thing,laestabNo: blah blah, [lots more things]   institutionId: blah blah,name: last thing,laestabNo: blah blah
```

The desired output is:

```
1st thing,laestabNo: blah blah  2nd thing,laestabNo: blah blah, [lots more things]  last thing,laestabNo: blah blah
```

The command I am using within a powershell script:

```
Powershell -NoProfile "(Get-Content -Raw .\allacts.txt) -replace 'institutionid.*,name', '' | Out-File -FilePath allacts.txt -Force -Encoding ASCII"
```

What I actually get is:

```
last thing,laestabNo:blah blah
```

And nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in regex, the `.` means one character. the `*` means zero or more of the previous character. so you are telling it to replace EVERYTHING from the 1st `institutionid` to the last `,name`. [*grin*] take a look at "greedy & lazy matches" for how to limit that.

Comment: Thanks yeah I see that now. Just goes to show a little bit of RTFM sometimes beats hours of head-keyboard-smacking.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct for your use case.
You mean this...

```
$SomeString = 'institutionId: blah blah,name: 1st thing,laestabNo: blah blah   institutionId: blah blah,name: 2nd thing,laestabNo: blah blah, [lots more things]   institutionId: blah blah,name: last thing,laestabNo: blah blah'
Clear-Host
# RegEx to replace all text string patterns and the text between them
$SomeString -Replace '(institutionId: ).*?(name: )'
# Results
<#
1st thing,laestabNo: blah blah   2nd thing,laestabNo: blah blah, [lots more things]   last thing,laestabNo: blah blah
#>
```